# Need help with dimensions of kernels

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I need to find the dimension of the kernel of the linear transformations [d/dx] and [d/dx + 2x] on a function y (x).
For d/dx, I'm assuming that this is just solving y'(x) = 0. And the solution would just be y = c. Now does this mean the kernel has dimension 0 or 1? 
For [d/dx + 2x], I'm guessing the dimension of the kernel for this one is definitely 1. 
Ps: the reason why I'm asking is because it seems a little too easy and I feel like I've done something wrong.

Comment: Remember the definiton of the dimension of a vector space is the length (or number of elements) of any basis. So you can just find a basis and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, note that you can write the solution as $y=cx^0$. This should help you figure out the dimension for that part.

For the second part, the solution to the differential equation $y'+2xy=0$ is $y=ce^{-x^2}$.

If I am to presume that the vector space for this question is the set of all polynomials, note that this solution is only a polynomial when c=0. From here, you can see what is in the kernel, and then find the dimension, if you can recall a certain defined value for the dimension.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yes, the vector space is the set of all polynomials. I still have no idea what these results mean in relation to the dimension. I'm having issues setting up the kernel matrices. Sorry, the concept of differentiation as a linear transformation is very new to me.

Comment: The (polynomial) solutions you find are what is contained in the kernel, hence why we set the differential equation to equal zero. Think back to the definition of the kernel, and you should understand why.

Comment: This makes me think the dimensions of the kernels for both cases is 1. I hope this is correct.

Comment: You are correct for the first part. But for the second part, what do you remember about the zero vector space and the dimension?

Comment: That it has a dimension of 0 I believe.

Comment: Yes, you're correct